# Getting all constants within a class in python

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, constants

I have a class which is essentially used to define common constants for other classes.  It looks something like the following:

```
class CommonNames(object):
    C1 = 'c1'
    C2 = 'c2'
    C3 = 'c3'
```

And I want to get all of the constant values "pythonically".  If I used `CommonNames.__dict__.values()` I get those values (`'c1'`, etc.) but I get other things such as:

```
<attribute '__dict__' of 'CommonNames' objects>,
<attribute '__weakref__' of 'CommonNames' objects>,
None ...
```

Which I don't want.

I want to be able to grab all the values because this code will be changed later and I want other places to know about those changes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You'll have to filter those out explicitly by filtering on names:

```
[value for name, value in vars(CommonNames).iteritems() if not name.startswith('_')]
```

This produces a list of values for any name not starting with an underscore:

```
>>> class CommonNames(object):
...     C1 = 'c1'
...     C2 = 'c2'
...     C3 = 'c3'
... 
>>> [value for name, value in vars(CommonNames).iteritems() if not name.startswith('_')]
['c3', 'c2', 'c1']
```

For enumerations like these, you'd be better of using the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34/) of the new [`enum` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) added to Python 3.4:

```
from enum import Enum

class CommonNames(Enum):
    C1 = 'c1'
    C2 = 'c2'
    C3 = 'c3'

values = [e.value for e in CommonNames]
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to use Martijn example in python3, you should use items() instead of iteritmes(), since it's deprecated

```python
[value for name, value in vars(CommonNames).items() if not name.startswith('_')]
```